# ColdFusion replacelist reorders returned string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to clean up submitted file names.

I'm using `replacelist(filename,"',##,&, ",",,and,-")` which should

- remove `'` and `#`
- replace `&` with `and`
- replace spaces with `-`.

When given `"apost's & pound#.JPG"`, instead of returning:

```
    "aposts-and-pound.jpg"
```

replaceList returns:

```
    "apostandspound-.JPG"
```

I'm using ColdFusion 10.

Comment: +1 for a nice question from a 1st-timer. Welcome to stackoverflow:)

Answer (score 8):

This is not reordering - it is due to how the CF list processing works - empty elements are ignored/removed.

Some of the List~ string processing functions have an additional argument to change this behaviour (i.e. treat empty elements as an empty string), but ReplaceList doesn't appear to.

You can solve this by doing the removals in a separate step to the replacements:

```
<cfset NewFilename = rereplace(Filename,"['##]","","all") />
<cfset NewFilename = replacelist(NewFilename,"&, ","and,-") />
```

or

```
replacelist( rereplace(filename,"['##]","","all") , "&, " , "and,-" )
```

Comment: You might wanna raise an enhancement request for that shortgall in `replaceList()`, @Peter?

Comment: Hmm, was about to go raise an issue for Railo also, but looks like it already behaves as expected (no IncludeEmptyFields required). Now I don't know whether it's worth raising a compatibility issue, given that this is almost certainly preferred behaviour and hopefully going to change with CF? :/

Comment: cheers, I've voted. I'd still *mention* it to Railo maybe, just so they know, but I think the Railo behaviour is correct here. Good news.